# Request timeout for web api request in Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2

I am using an api which takes more time to give response. If I tested the web api that was deployed in IIS from postman, It works without any time out. If I tested the same api that was deployed in azure, It gave me timeout.

Somewhere I read that you need to set the timeout in client application. I used postman in both cases. I verified the timeout for postman. It is infinity.

Can you give me the solution?

Comment: You said that it gives you timeout - every time or you have successful requests? You use Azure Web Apps?

Comment: Every time it gives me timeout. we deployed web api2 in azure.

Comment: Ok, then it is not the intermittent issue. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you hit the default timeout of Azure Web Apps (i think it is 3 minutes, if i remember correctly). Could you set SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT from the portal - web app settings => app settings => add the setting with the needed value (to say 360 (in seconds)). [Reference](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings).